# Inconsistency in T-SQL stored procedure with null comparison checking

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which contains a null comparison of

```
--cutting the declaration of various variables
SELECT @val = id FROM dbo.example_table
WHERE type=@type AND date=@date

if @val = null
    insert record
```

When this is executed in the stored procedure with an empty table, this will insert the record, however when this is executed as a block of code outside the stored proc, it will not perform the insert. There are also other SQL servers on which the insert will never be made, whether inside or outside the stored proc.

Is there some explanation for why his can work in some situations but not in others? I know the correct way to perform the comparison is `@val IS NULL`, but i was curious to to whether `@val = null` was documented anywhere for completeness.

Comment: A [`SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) would cause this ... (If thats the case you should remove it and rewrite using the documented way to deal with nulls)

Comment: You never compare null to anything - use `is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the setting for [ANSI_NULLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).

This would return a **false**:

```
declare @var varchar(10) = null;

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
if (@var = null) select 'true';
else select 'false';
```

This would return a **true**:

```
declare @var varchar(10) = null;

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
if (@var = null) select 'true';
else select 'false';
```